# _tkinter.TclError: CLIPBOARD selection doesn't exist or form "STRING" not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm testing a client/server clipboard sharing program (because RDP doesn't for reasons i couldn't find). It works fine, but when i activate the client's clipboard writing code, the server thread crashes about 20 seconds after a copy:

> _tkinter.TclError: CLIPBOARD selection doesn't exist or form "STRING" not defined

What am i doing wrong? Here's my code, which i ran in two command windows using `python share_clipboard.py S` and `python share_clipboard.py C localhost`:

```
"""
Share clipboard
by Cees Timmerman
01-12-2014 v0.1
"""

import socket, sys, threading
from time import sleep
try: from tkinter import Tk  # Python 3
except: from Tkinter import Tk

def dec(s):
    return s.decode('utf-8')
def enc(s):
    return s.encode('utf-8')

# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17453212/multi-threaded-tcp-server-in-python
class ClientThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(my, sock):
        threading.Thread.__init__(my)
        my.sock = sock

    def run(my):    
        print("Connection from : %s:%s" % (ip, str(port)))
        #my.sock.send(enc("\nWelcome to the server\n\n"))
        '''
        data = "dummydata"
        while len(data):
            data = dec(clientsock.recv(2048))
            print("Client sent : "+data)
            my.sock.send(enc("You sent me : "+data))
        '''
        old_clip = None
        while True:
            new_clip = tk.clipboard_get()
            if new_clip != old_clip:
                print("New clip: %r" % new_clip)
                old_clip = new_clip
                my.sock.sendall(enc(new_clip))
            sleep(1)
        print("Client disconnected...")

if 1 < len(sys.argv) < 4:
    cs = sys.argv[1]
    ip = sys.argv[2] if len(sys.argv) == 3 else "0.0.0.0"
else:
    print("Usage: %s <C|S> [IP]")
    sys.exit()

tk = Tk()
port = 9999

if cs == "S":

    tcpsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    tcpsock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

    tcpsock.bind((ip, port))
    threads = []

    # Listen for connections.
    while True:
        tcpsock.listen(4)
        print("\nListening for incoming connections...")
        (clientsock, (ip, port)) = tcpsock.accept()
        newthread = ClientThread(clientsock)
        newthread.start()
        threads.append(newthread)

    # Wait for threads to finish.
    for t in threads:
        t.join()
else:
    clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    clientsocket.connect((ip, port))
    while True:
        data = clientsocket.recv(1024)
        print(data)
        #tk.withdraw()
        #tk.clipboard_clear()
        #tk.clipboard_append(data)  # Causes error on server: _tkinter.TclError: CLIPBOARD selection doesn't exist or form "STRING" not defined
        #tk.destroy()
```

Comment: In my experience, Tkinter generally behaves strangely when combined with threading. It may be necessary to design your project so all calls to Tk methods are made only in the main thread.

Comment: @Kevin `new_clip = tk.clipboard_get()` in the main server loop (using `tcpsock.settimeout(5)`) didn't help.

Comment: The `clipboard` module works. Too bad Python didn't work out of the box.

Comment: `clipboard` uses `pyperclip` which [can't handle fancy quotes.](https://gist.github.com/CTimmerman/370271d0519f3c8db749)

Comment: `win32clipboard` [correctly handles Unicode](https://gist.github.com/CTimmerman/133cb80100357dde92d8).

Answer (score 0):

I found this post when searching solutions for my problem but it does not help so I solved it by myself and post the answer here.

## Understanding error message is the first step to solve the problem.

> _tkinter.TclError: CLIPBOARD selection doesn't exist or form "STRING" not defined

The message says that there 2 possibilities for this to happen:

1. CLIPBOARD selection doesn't exist
2. form "STRING" not defined

*<1. CLIPBOARD selection doesn't exist>* may be easier to understand. No text has been selected, so the clipboard is empty, so *tk.clipboard_get()* produced error.

*<2. form "STRING" not defined>* is harder to understand. Below is the reference page for clipboard_get() method :
[image: clipboard_get]

The reference says that Tkinter sets STRING as default type for the value that returned by *clipboard_get()* . So if there is something else currently in your clipboard (file names, etc), error may happend (you accidentially copy files instead of text ?)

## Solution

My problem was to handle Copying the current text in the Entry Widget, so I solved my issue by:

1. Clear the clipboard first with *clipboard_clear*
2. Select all text present in the widget
3. Append selected text to the clipboard with *clipboard_append*

You have a different problem so you have to find a suitable solution for you by reading references.

## References

- Tkinter Manual: https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/clipboard.htm
- List of types in ICCCM terminology: https://www.x.org/docs/ICCCM/icccm.pdf page 12, 13

Comment: ChatGPT is only being redundant here.