# Run WebSocket server in Thread

Tags: python, multithreading, websocket

this is probably more a question about threading than about my websocket.
I'm using "SimpleWebSocket" from github ( https://github.com/dpallot/simple-websocket-server )
The example works fine:

```
from SimpleWebSocketServer import SimpleWebSocketServer, WebSocket

class SimpleEcho(WebSocket):

    def handleMessage(self):
        # echo message back to client
        self.sendMessage(self.data)

    def handleConnected(self):
        print self.address, 'connected'

    def handleClose(self):
        print self.address, 'closed'

server = SimpleWebSocketServer('', 8000, SimpleEcho)
server.serveforever()
```

The Server is running, I can connect and send Messages.

Now i try to run it as a Thread with those classes:
This one is supposed to create many threads including the WebSocketServer

```
from websockethread import WebSocketThread
class startManyThreads:
    def __init__(self):
        self.thread1 = WebSocketThread()
        self.thread1.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    startManyThreads = startManyThreads()
```

This class should run as my thread:

```
import threading
from SimpleWebSocketServer import SimpleWebSocketServer
from webSocketServer import WebSocketServer

class WebSocketThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        server = SimpleWebSocketServer('', 8000, WebSocketServer)
        server.serveforever()
```

And this is the "customized" echo example:

```
from SimpleWebSocketServer import SimpleWebSocketServer, WebSocket

class SimpleEcho(WebSocket):

    def handleMessage(self):
        # echo message back to client
        self.sendMessage(self.data)

    def handleConnected(self):
        print self.address, 'connected'

    def handleClose(self):
        print self.address, 'closed'
```

I have also tried to derive this: `class SimpleEcho(WebSocket, threading.Thread):`

Any Ideas what i'm doing wrong?
&
Thanks alot in advance!

Edit:
The result when i run "simpleEcho" is that i get a prompt can connect via the websocket.html (provided on github), send and receive Messages

The result when i put it in a thread (anyone of the 3 ways i tried) is the same behaviour except when i try to "connect" from the websocket.html i get a "error: undefined". With nmap i checked and the Server seems so be running & listening to port 8000

Edit 2: Derived new Class from SimpleWebSocketServer

```
import threading

from SimpleWebSocketServer import SimpleWebSocketServer

class ThreadSimpleWebSocketThread(threading.Thread, SimpleWebSocketServer):
    def __init__(self, serversocket):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.serversocket = serversocket

    def serveforever(self):
        SimpleWebSocketServer.serversocket = self.serversocket
        SimpleWebSocketServer.selectInterval = 0.1
        SimpleWebSocketServer.listeners = [self.serversocket]
        super(ThreadSimpleWebSocketThread, self).serveforever()

    def run(self):
        self.serveforever()
```

Comment: What is the expected behavior and actual behavior?

Comment: Expected behaviour would be that i can connect with the "test Client" provided on the github. Actual behaviour is, that i'm getting an "undefined error" (on the test "Homepage") as soon as i run it a as a thread. no Errors elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

The main problem seems to be *where* you're starting the server. The `Thread.__init__()` method runs inside the main thread (of the *caller*), not the actual `WebSocketThread()`. This needs to be done in the `Thread.run()` method:

```
class WebSocketThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        server = SimpleWebSocketServer('', 8000, WebSocketServer)
        server.serveforever()
```

The code inside `run()` actually runs inside the thread.

Note that because of the Global Interpreter Lock, threads won't improve performance much, and you'll probably need `multiprocessing`. However, if you just want to offload the I/O waiting, this should work fine.

**Edit**: From looking at this GitHub project, and rethinking what you're trying to do, this isn't trivial. You'll have to override `WebSocket.serveforever()` in your `SimpleEcho()` class and change it to accept the socket and pass the accepted socket to a `Thread` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17453212/multi-threaded-tcp-server-in-python)).

Comment: I use the threads because there is a bunch of other stuff done simultaniously. I already tried this method aswell. From the Python side it Looks like its working (just a blank prompt in the console - like the standalone Version had) but i always get the error in the error "undefined"

Comment: Can you edit and show the complete code at the bottom after making the fixes here in my answer?

Comment: It is exactly the code above (from my Initial post) and the "WebSocketThread" class is this one from your post (copy & paste). It seems to be running but I cant connect. nmap also Shows me the port 8000 is opend and listening

Comment: I'm trying to override serverforever() in SimpleEcho. The Problem im having now is that serveforever() is a method of SimpleWebSocketServer and this on is derived from object. the only Connection between SimpleWebSocketServer and WebSocket is the Argument in the constructor of SimpleWebSocketServer. Do i have to Change the serveforver() method to accectp the socket?

Comment: Sorry, what I should have said, was extend `SimpleWebSocketServer()` to make a `ThreadedSimpleWebSocketServer()` (and use that instead), then override `serveforever()` making it pass the sockets to new threads.

Comment: I tried that now with the same result as above. I create the socket in my main and give it to the ThreadSimpleWebSocketThread(self.serversocket). In the ThreadSimpleWebSocketThread Class  i override serveforever and set the SimpleWebSocketServer.serversocket and afterwards run super(ThreadSimpleWebSocketThread, self).serveforever(). Port is again open, application seems to be running but i can not connect

Comment: Can you show your new code with the new `ThreadedSimpleWebSocket`?

Comment: I edited the original post. I also tried to Access the variables with self.varName in the serveforever() with the same result. e.g. self.selectInterval = 0.1

Comment: Ah I see. Unfortunately this will be much more complex. You'll basically have to copy and paste the code from `SimpleWebSocketServer .serveforever()` and change the `accept()` logic to pass the sockets of the accepted connections to a new thread you create each time.

Comment: ok. Tank you for your help. Just one more question for my understanding. once serveforever() is called i will get executed until the Programm is terminated. I'm running a msg-Q (zeroMQ) and want to interact (send & receive Messages) with the zeroMQ and the webapplication which i guess will not work with this Kind of Programm logic